# Buscar Linux directorios con mismo nombre entre directorios masivamente

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

Estoy tratando de buscar una serie de directorios (carpetas) que se que están repetidos pero, está tan anidado que estoy tratando de llegar a ellos con una expresión regular y que me devuelva la localización de los mismos. Así sería el árbol de búsqueda:

```
└── padre
      └── hijo1
            └──hijo1
                  └──nombre1
      └── hijo2
            └──hijo1
                  └──nombre2
      └── hijo3
            └──hijo1
                  └──nombre3            
      └── hijo4
            └──hijo1
                  └──nombre1
```

Tendría que devolverme algo así:

```
/padre/hijo1/hijo1/nombre1
/padre/hijo4/hijo1/nombre1
```

Es decir, necesito saber qué nombres finales están repetidos en una lista. Hay cientos de carpetas, por eso necesito algo como esto.

Edito. Por si ayuda, el nombre del directorio acaba en '.as'. No es una extensión sino que lleva ese sufijo.

Comment: ¿Que intentaste? ¿Cual fue el impedimento para avanazar? ¿Con que problema te encontraste?

Comment: Que mi conocimiento en búsquedas es inexistente :9

Comment: Bueno he utilizado este comando enviando a un txt todos los archivos y en Excel busco coincidencias.     find -name "*.as*" -printf '%p \n' > /tmp/archivo.txt

Comment: Tengo una duda, cuando te referís a repetidos, te referís a nombres o a contenido? Tambíen esperás encontrar directorios o solo archivos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me adelanto y contesto lo que creo que necesitás, que es buscar nombres de archivos repetidos:

```
find padre -mindepth 1 -type f -printf '%p %f\n' | sort -t ' ' -k 2,2 | uniq -f 1 --all-repeated=separate | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Siendo:

```
padre
    El directorio desde donde empezar a buscar
-mindepth 1
    Procesar todos los archivos a partir del nivel actual.
-type f
    Buscamos únicamente archivos (file).
-printf '%p %f\n'
    Imprimimos directorio y nombre del archivo, agregando un salto de linea al final
| sort -t ' ' -k 2,2
    Pasamos la salida del find al sort, seteando como separador de campos el ' ' y utilizando la segunda columna devuelta por el find para ordenar
| uniq -f 1 --all-repeated=separate
    Pasamos la salida del sort al uniq, evitando comparar la primera columna e imprimiendo los duplicados separando los grupos mediante una linea nueva
| cut -d' ' -f1
    Pasamos la salida del uniq al cut, seteando el delimitador en ' ' y filtrando unicamente la fila 1 a partir del delimitador
```

En donde con la siguiente estructura de directorios/archivos (Siendo nombre* archivos y padre e hijo* directorios):

```
padre/
├── hijo1
│   └── hijo1
│       └── nombre1
├── hijo2
│   └── hijo1
│       └── nombre2
└── hijo3
    └── hijo1
        └── nombre1
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
padre/hijo1/hijo1/nombre1
padre/hijo3/hijo1/nombre1
```

Comment: Perfecto, este es justo el que necesitaba! Probado y funcionando

Comment: @Qadesh me alegro que te haya servido. No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada para ayudar a los demás que tengan la misma duda.

Comment: Si, lo he probado además en dos entornos más que tengo y listo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con `awk`.

```
find padre -mindepth 3 -type d | awk -F / '
!count[$NF]++ {
    registros[$NF] = $0
    next
}
count[$NF] == 2 {
    print registros[$NF]
    delete registros[$NF]
}
{print}'
```

Donde:

- `-mindepth 3` es suponiendo que quieres obtener los duplicados del tercer nivel de profundidad:

  ```
  padre/<primer nivel>/<segundo nivel>/<tercer y último nivel>
  ```
- `-type d` indica que se buscaran archivos tipo directorio, puesto que eso entendí de tu pregunta, pero la respuesta de Magus muestra bien la opción `-type f` en caso de archivos normales.

La explicación con `awk` puede ser un poco enredada, pero es simple.

Primero, el parámetro `-F /` muestra que se usa `/` como separador.

Respecto al código:

```
!count[$NF]++ { #  Añade en el array "count" el último campo (el campo 4 en caso de que sean 3 niveles 
                #+ (el padre mas los tres "hijos")) como clave (con $NF) y genera un conteo que se guarda como valor.

# Todo este bloque se ejecuta en el caso de que el valor de "count[$NF]" no se haya visto antes.

    registros[$NF] = $0 # En el array "registros", se añade un nuevo elemento con el campo 4 (el nombre de la última capeta)
                        # como clave, y el registro entero (la dirección completa) como valor.

    next # Evita todas las instrucciones subsecuentes y cambia al siguiente registro.
}
count[$NF] == 2 { # En el caso de que el campo (el último campo) esté duplicado,
#                                 |
#                                 |
    print registros[$NF]  # imprime el registro correspondiente,
    delete registros[$NF] # luego borra el registro para no guardarlo en memoria.
}
{print}
```

El resultado de este comando da:

```
padre/hijo1/hijo1/nombre1
padre/hijo4/hijo1/nombre1
```